# Does the Celestial Armor require medium armor proficiency?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, armor, proficiency

**TL;DR: Does the Celestial Armor require medium armor proficiency?**

I found the [Celestial Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/celestial-armor/) which said that it is a **medium armor** [Chainmail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/armor/chainmail)+3, and is light enough to be considered as **light armor**.

But, does it work just like a [Chainmail](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/chainmail/) made from [Celestial Mithral](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment-/special-materials#TOC-Mithral), which then makes the armor light enough to be considered as **light armor**, but still requires **medium armor** proficiency? After all, it does seem to be made from it, even if it doesn't state it.

When checking other armors, I found the [Elven Chain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/elven-chain/) which state that it is a [Chainmail](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/chainmail/), but should be considered as **light armor**, even from the proficiency point of view. But it also state that it is made from **Mithral** unlike the [Celestial Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/celestial-armor/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paizo creative director James Jacobs in a 2010 Paizo message board [post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kmr4?Celestial-Armor-confusion-and-are-Full-Plates#2), in part, says

> Celestial armor is not mithral—it's actually made of silver or gold (as mentioned in its description), and thus doesn't gain any of the standard modifiers for being mithral at all. It's its own thing. Its lower arcane spell failure and higher max Dex bonus are a result of its magical qualities, not what it's made out of. **In addition, this magic allows folks to wear it as if it were light armor**—the mithral versions don't do this because mithral isn't fundamentally magical like the enhancements on celestial armor.

Thus, according to Jacobs, [this FAQ entry](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t7t) on proficiency with mithral armors doesn't apply to [*celestial armor*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/celestial-armor/), making it so folks who are only proficient with light armor can wear the *celestial armor* normally.

While not a rules guy, Jacobs frequently fields technical and not-so-technical *Pathfinder* questions, and his opinions often carry at least some weight with fans. Even if such opinions aren't *officially* official, they're often the best fans can expect.

Comment: As he is an official from the company, its words mean that they are the words from the company (unless said otherwise by the company).

Comment: @vdubus O, I agree, I only hedge because some folks here in the past have (rightly, in my opinion) pointed out that Jacobs isn't an official *rules* source, even though he may be an official *Pathfinder* source. Bulhman, for instance, were he to say differently, would—for lack of a better term—outrank Jacobs's pronouncement.

Comment: Chain mail is medium armor, his wording makes it sound like mitral for being treated like light instead of medium, so it should still required med prof.

Comment: @Fering RE: Jacobs's "wording makes it sound like mit[h]ral for being treated like light instead of medium, so it should still required med[ium armor] prof[iciency]." I'm sorry, but I can't determine the antecedents of the *it*s in that sentence. I mean, mithral chainmail, according to the FAQ and Jacobs, *really does* require medium armor proficiency. Jacobs here is just making it clear that the FAQ entry applies to mithral armors and doesn't apply to *celestial armor* because *celestial armor* straight up is *not* mithral.

Comment: Im not trying to apply just mithral to it, just that armors being treated as light when its medium still require the proficiency of medium

Comment: @Fering Is it possible you're generalizing that FAQ entry? That is, the FAQ entry covers *specifically* mithral armor. While that FAQ entry *could* be read broadly and extended to other *nonmithral* armors that are — for whatever reason — *also* treated as lighter than normal, that's not what that FAQ entry actually *says*, and Jacobs repeats that distinction here. If you're not generalize the FAQ entry, you're going to have to make your point clearer here or in your answer. (Note that one of your answer's upvotes is mine; I, too, had originally automatically generalized that FAQ entry!)

Comment: Yes, I appear to be using it in a general sense since it is the only material that allows you to treat it as a lower ...weight?... armor. None of the wood or hide ones allow you to treat it that way.

Answer (score 4):

**No, Celestial Armor does not require medium armor proficiency.**

Compare these texts:

From [Celestial Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/celestial-armor/)

> It is considered light armor.

Versus from [Mithral](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral) (my emphasis)

> Most mithral armors are one category lighter than normal *for purposes of movement and other limitations*. Heavy armors are treated as medium, and medium armors are treated as light, but light armors are still treated as light. *This decrease does not apply to proficiency in wearing the armor*.

In otherwords, Mithral medium armor acts like light armor in many ways. Celestial Chainmail *is* light armor.

(I think James Jacob's explanation--quoted in another answer--is helpful, and agrees with this conclusion, but in this case the written rules themselves are a more primary source.)

Answer (score 2):

It does not say it is light enough to be considered light armor. The text clearly states that it is a light armor.

> It is considered light armor

Therefor you don't need medium armor proficiency.

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted? It correctly cites the rules for the Celestial Armor.

Comment: @MikeQ, I don't know, but I suppose that it is because I was asking if the **considered** part was working like for armors made of Mithral, or if it was really meaning that it was a light armor. After all, the [Elven Chain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/elven-chain/) does specify that it is light armor, even from the proficiency point of view.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you still need medium.

Located under the special materials rules for [mithral](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Mithral) in the FAQ

> Most mithral armors are one category lighter than normal for purposes of movement and other limitations. Heavy armors are treated as medium, and medium armors are treated as light, but light armors are still treated as light. This decrease does not apply to proficiency in wearing the armor.

Comment: The question is asking about Celestial Armor, not mithral armor.

Comment: Both are considered light armor, and since the celestial armor is made out of most likely celestial mithral, it applies

Comment: Could you provide a source saying that Celestial Armor is made from mithral?

Comment: I cant because since its a specific magic item they didnt feel that such details were important to provide to us, but chainmail is 40 pounds normally so it must be made out of something that provides the weight reduction, so since it does not also provide DR as if it were Adamantine and its still metal and not wood, so it must be mithral as there are no other early special materials that reduce the weight.